Projectile GDB Remote I/O
Trying to debug a remote application. On a different architecture system and have the I/O flooding my GUD command window. I'm wondering how I can launch gdb or configure GUD in a way to get the remote I/O. So far this is what I have and gdb is launched as follows. I am using doomemacs with Emacs 29.3.
M-x projectile-run-gdb

/sdk/path/arm-...-gdb -i=mi -cd . ./path/to/app

(gdb) target extended-remote | ssh -T root@$arg0 gdbserver --multi -
(gdb) set remote exec-file /home/root/app
Remote debugging using stdio
(gdb) 

